# Live streaming video in Qt

Tags: qt, gstreamer, qt5, qtmultimedia

I am making a "simple" software that can streaming video (without audio) from pc to pc. I am a newbie in Qt so I have some questions:

- Does Qt 5.1 have any class to Encode and Decode video?
- If not, can I use other libraries (such as gstreamer) to Codec the video? And how can I import them into a Qt based project.

I need all of your advice. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Decoding is no problem. You can use the `QMediaPlayer` class. Under Linux it actually uses the gstreamer libs. Encoding is not implemented. This is a bit beyond the scope of Qt5. And don't let the classes `QMediaRecorder` or `QVideoEncoderSettings` confuse you. They are mainly helper classes for `QCamera` or `QRadioTuner`, which provide an already encoded stream from their devices. If you need to encode single images into video frames and put them into a container, you need a 3rd party lib like ffmpeg.

Streaming a video from on pc to another is easily implemented with Qt5. Encoding or transcoding cannot be done with Qt5 alone.